# Does document.getElementById(thebutton).onclick = null remove the event from a button?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm confused by the following question:

```
document.getElementById(thebutton).onclick = null; removes the onclick event from thebutton element.
```

**Options to choose: Yes or No.**

I chose "No" because I thought setting `null` to `onclick` just removed the event handler, not the event itself. However, the answer was "Yes"!

Did I misunderstand the question or the answer was wrong ?

PS: The question from "Developing in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS3 Jump Start" course of Microsoft Virtual Academy.

Comment: I don't get it? The "event" is when someone actually clicks the element, and that triggers an "event handler". You can't remove an "event", as in the action that triggers the "handler", the user can still click the element until his finger falls of, you can only remove the "event handler".

Comment: @adeneo So do I!That is the exact question I got from the course http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/Content/ViewContent.aspx?et=1949&m=1947&ct=13949#?fbid=HHaaTh3eQ11. Go to "READY TO TAKE SELF-ASSESSMENT?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not [testing](http://jsfiddle.net/nBJJu/) it ?

As you can see in this Fiddle, the event is obviously not removed. So either the question is wrong and should be :

```
removes the onclick event handler from thebutton element
```

Or the actual answer is wrong.

Comment: P I have tested, but not sure, so I asked!

Answer (score 1):

The question is not well worded and should be corrected, but I don't believe that would have tripped me because I wouldn't consider the possibility of "removing an event" since it's obviously not possible. Events themselves are not removed. I've personally interchanged the phrases "remove the event" with "remove the event handler," so I think it's not that grievous or deceptive a question.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for the update and making the question clearer. I just didn't get it when I took the course.

Comment: I wouldn't say the question trips the user. The fact that it IS impossible makes it false, IMHO :). Thanks Jeremy.

Answer (score -1):

I chose no because it should be document.getElementById("thebutton").onclick = null;

getElementById can't be called with a reference.

Comment: Yes it can. `var thebutton = "thebutton"; document.getElementById(thebutton).onclick = null;` will work just fine?